# JQuery Carousel - shifting UL not LIs

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I am using the JQuery Carousel plugin from here: http://www.thomaslanciaux.pro/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm

I have set it up as such:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(".carousel").carousel();
    });
</script>

<div id="carouselholder">
<div class="carousel">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="images/2.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="images/3.jpg" alt=""></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div><!--CAROUSELHOLDER-->
```

But when I hit the Next button it seems to shift the whole `ul` not the `li`.

Does anyone know how to fix this? (or maybe theres a better plugin?)

Below: Screen shot from Element Inspector:

[image]

Comment: It moves an absolutely positioned <ul> inside a relatively positioned wrapper, what problem do you see?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté according to the documentation is should be moving the <li>s, not the <ul> and I am not sure how to amend this

Comment: Yes, the children of the `ul` will be animated to the left when the `ul` does. I meant, what's the issue - does it move all the `li`s at a time or something?

Comment: Yes, it moves all li at the same time

Comment: Oh deleted answer, I didn't see the JS previously. Mhm, your setup seems just fine.

Comment: I tried to make a fiddle with the basic example and it seemed broken too. Maybe try [cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/), [bjqs](http://basic-slider.com/) or [camera](http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/) if you don't get that plugin working.

Comment: Yeah - ended up using Cycle, worked instantly: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/nowrap.html

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on this plugin seems a bit slim. It appears that some additional styling is needed to make it work, but none of the examples illustrate this point.

Your setup is correct and in fact it will move the entire UL grouping, only showing the currently selected li. Using your simple code above, all I did was add the following CSS to make it work:

```
li {
  float: left;
}
```

Just add a little more styling to your container to constrain the view and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is how it is meant to work

if you put a width on the carousel-wrap, so it only shows one image, the ul shifts position to show the next one

The li tags dont move

If you want to try another plugin, i recommend this one
http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/index.php .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help all, but I found that a modified version the Cycle plugin works a lot better:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/nowrap.html